# Reshape 1D vector into multiple matrices properly (numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Given a 1 dimensional vector, I have to split it and reshape it
in order to fit with a list of matrices. The order matters. Here I have a working example:

```
import numpy as np

def setWeights(odlW: list, newW: np.ndarray) -> list:

    assert newW.shape[0] == sum(map(np.size, odlW)) # total nb weights

    for i, w in enumerate(odlW):
        if i == 0:
            odlW[i] = newW[:w.size].reshape(odlW[i].shape)
        else:
            odlW[i] = newW[odlW[i - 1].size : odlW[i - 1].size + odlW[i].size].reshape(w.shape)

    return odlW

shape = [2, 3, 4, 1]
weights = [np.ones((y, x)) for x, y in zip(shape[:-1], shape[1:])]

for w in weights:
    print("w {}".format(w.shape))
    print(w)
```

which gives :

```
w (3, 2)
[[1. 1.]
 [1. 1.]
 [1. 1.]]
w (4, 3)
[[1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]]
w (1, 4)
[[1. 1. 1. 1.]]
```

and after calling the function, everything works well:

```
# there are 22 weights
newVec = np.zeros((22, 1))
weights = setWeights(weights,newVec)
for w in weights:
    print("w {}".format(w.shape))
    print(w)
```

which gives:

```
w (3, 2)
[[0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]]
w (4, 3)
[[0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]
w (1, 4)
[[0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

However, I really dislike the shape of the function, I cannot change the data structure but if someone knows how to solve this properly (maybe with builtin numpy functions) it would be really helpful.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Does `setWeights` supposed to do nothing?

Comment: @Yoskutik ok, maybe is not clear. setWeights must change the weights, which are a list of matrices, according to the given vector.

Comment: as you can see, initially all for all matrices and for all weights the value is one. There are 22 weights in total for all matrices. I give a vector of 22 values equal to 0 to the function and the result is now that all weights are 0